# Minify Extjs4 for production

Tags: extjs, minify, extjs4.1

i have been trying to follow the documentation for minifying extjs4 but have not made much headaway ...

The application structure is as such

```
webapp
+---resources
¦   +---css
¦   +---images
¦   +---app
¦       +---controller
¦       +---model
¦       +---store
¦       +---view
¦       app.js
¦       login.js
+---WEB-INF
    +---classes
    +---spring
    ¦   +---appServlet
    +---views
        home.jsp
+---login.html
```

The web.xml's welcome file list is login.html which contains the login.js . On authentication the user is redirected to home.jsp which contains app.js.

How do i minify this using sencha sdk ? I have tried a couple of options (mostly hacks) to see how the output would work but the all-classes.js turns out empty or with one or two classes but never my custom .js within the app folder ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using http://www.sencha.com/products/sdk-tools/download/, the sdk took (afaik) basically spiders the application, trying to load it as if it's a regular user. So I suggest modifying the app.json such that url: points to a spiderable version of the app. Even if the behavior is to bump out unauthenticated users, it's enough for the sencha command to find and traverse your class structures.

And I'm assuming here that you correctly used requires statements in each of your your various classes.